# Padding a multindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe of US opinion poll data that I'm trying to pad out on a daily basis. I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the original data (the dataframe doesn't have to be a multiindex).

```
                  Democratic         Other  Republican
Date       State                                                
2008-11-04 AZ       0.451153      0.012495    0.536352
2012-05-20 AZ       0.462500      0.000000    0.537500
...
2008-11-04 WI       0.562178      0.014686    0.423137
2012-11-03 WI       0.515152      0.000000    0.484848
```

I want to pad it out so it looks something like this:

```
                  Democratic         Other  Republican
Date       State                                                
2008-11-04 AZ       0.451153      0.012495    0.536352
2008-11-05 AZ       0.451153      0.012495    0.536352
...
2012-05-20 AZ       0.462500      0.000000    0.537500
2012-05-21 AZ       0.462500      0.000000    0.537500
...
2012-11-06 AZ       0.462500      0.000000    0.537500
...
2008-11-04 WI       0.562178      0.014686    0.423137
2008-11-05 WI       0.562178      0.014686    0.423137
...
2012-11-03 WI       0.515152      0.000000    0.484848
2012-11-04 WI       0.515152      0.000000    0.484848
2012-11-05 WI       0.515152      0.000000    0.484848
2012-11-06 WI       0.515152      0.000000    0.484848
```

I tried doing this:

```
election_range = pd.date_range('2008-11-06', '2012-11-06')
dailies.reindex(election_range, method='pad')
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer
```

I tried just indexing on the date, but I got an error that the index wasn't unique.

The obvious thing to do is to split the frame state-by-state, reindex, and combine the frames, but there must be a better way of doing it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
start = df.index.levels[0].min()
end = df.index.levels[0].max()
days = pd.date_range(start, end)
df.unstack().reindex(days).ffill().stack().sort_index(level=[1, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared - I think this approach is likely to work. The code as you've written doesn't work for me, but it's close enough. I'll get this working and post the answer here then mark the question as solved. I appreciate your help - thank you.

Comment: I had some bugs elsewhere in my code I had to fix, once I fixed them, this worked great.